# NameError and Incorrect number of bindings supplied SQLite code

Tags: python, database, sqlite, join, sql-insert

I have a temp table u that has two columns, keyword and URL with the actual keywords and URLs. I have two more tables, one that contains IDs for each keyword and one that contains IDs for each URL. I need to pull the keyword ID and the URL ID for the appropriate pairs from u into my permanent table URL_Keyword.

This is what I have so far, but I realize it's not working, I keep getting either:

```
tabU = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM u")
to_db=[( i['keyword'], i['URL']) for i in tabU]
cur.execute("INSERT INTO URL_Crawl_by_Keyword(Keyword_ID, URL_Crawl_ID) VALUES ((SELECT Keyword_ID FROM Keyword WHERE Keyword=?),(SELECT Unique_URL_ID FROM Unique_URL WHERE URL=?));", to_db))


ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 1500 supplied.
```

OR:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO URL_Crawl_by_Keyword(Keyword_ID, URL_Crawl_ID) VALUES ((SELECT Keyword_ID FROM Keyword WHERE Keyword=?),(SELECT Unique_URL_ID FROM Unique_URL WHERE URL=?));",(Keyword_ID, URL_Crawl_ID))
NameError: name 'Keyword_ID' is not defined
```

Comment: What is `to_db` and how is it defined? The same for  `Keyword_ID` and `URL_Crawl_ID` for your 2nd query.

Comment: Thanks, I updated it, to include the rest of the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can insert all the rows in one `INSERT` statement, instead of looping through the results of the `SELECT` query.

All you need is to join the table `u` to `Keyword` and `Unique_URL`:

```
sql = """
INSERT INTO URL_Crawl_by_Keyword(Keyword_ID, URL_Crawl_ID)
SELECT k.Keyword_ID, uu.Unique_URL_ID
FROM u
INNER JOIN Keyword k ON k.Keyword = u.Keyword
INNER JOIN Unique_URL uu ON uu.URL = u.URL;
"""
cur.execute(sql)
```

Comment: I think this is replicating rows though. I have a total of 12 million rows in table U and I'm ending up with 54 million in URL_Crawl_by_Keyword.

Comment: @MeredithAbrams do you mean that you get the same combination of the 2 ids many times?

Comment: No, that's to be expected - I just checked my URL table and it apparently has duplicates. This is my mistake! Thank you for your help!